# import SNP to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, snapshot

Is possible to import SNP file into a MySQL Database?

i have .snp file which always convert to csv first before import to MySQL using php.
i need to direct import .snp file without converting first.

thanks before

Answer (score 1):

SNP file is a binary format that is not compatible with MySQL server

if you want to avoid converting the SNP file to CSV, you can consider using a different format that is compatible with MySQL, such as TSV or JSON -- you will need to make sure that your data is properly formatted and that it is consistent with the schema of your MySQL database.